# Invoke() is ignored when handling blazor events

Tags: c#, .net, event-handling, blazor, blazor-server-side

```
program.cs
builder.Services.AddScoped<ServiceInfoReceiveHandler>();
```

```
message_broker.cs
public MessageBroker(ServiceInfoReceiveHandler serviceInfoReceiveHandler)
{
    _handlers = new Dictionary<string, IReceiveHandler>
    {
        { "SVCMGMT/INSTALL/SVCINFO", serviceInfoReceiveHandler },
    };
    ReceiveMessage();
}
            
private void ReceiveMessage()
{           
    try
    {
        if (_handlers.ContainsKey(contentType))
        {
            _handlers[contentType].Receive(ea);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception($"No handler for content type '{contentType}'");
        }
    }
}
```

```
receive.cs
if (contentType == "")
{
  InstallServiceInfoReceived?.Invoke(this, (contentType, serverName, message));
}
```

```
ServiceInfoReceiveHandler.cs
public class ServiceInfoReceiveHandler : IReceiveHandler
{
  public event EventHandler<(string contentType, string serverName, string message)> InstallServiceInfoReceived;

  public void Receive(BasicDeliverEventArgs eventArgs)
  {
    var body = eventArgs.Body.ToArray();
    var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
    var serverName = eventArgs.BasicProperties.AppId;
    var contentType = eventArgs.BasicProperties.ContentType;

    if (contentType == "SVCMGMT/INSTALL/SVCINFO")
    {
      InstallServiceInfoReceived?.Invoke(this, (contentType, serverName, message));
    }
  }
}
```

```
install.razor
@inject ServiceInfoReceiveHandler _serviceInfoReceiveHandler

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
  _serviceInfoReceiveHandler.InstallServiceInfoReceived += OnServiceInfoReceived;
}

public void Dispose()
{
  _serviceInfoReceiveHandler.InstallServiceInfoReceived -= OnServiceInfoReceived;
}

private async void OnServiceInfoReceived(object sender, (string contentType, string serverName, string message) e)
{
...
}
```

I'm working with blazor and wanted to use an event handler like the one above.

This worked fine for the most part, but sometimes OnServiceInfoReceived would not get called.
I debugged it and found that
`InstallServiceInfoReceived?.Invoke();` was always called,
but after that `OnServiceInfoReceived()` was sometimes called and sometimes not.

Since it was intermittent and not constantly called, I wondered what the difference was.
It seemed to happen when testing each program at the same time with another developer.
However, I'm not sure if this could have an impact as I'm working locally on each of them running as localhost, even though they share a message broker and DB.

Could this be a problem?

Comment: My best guess is that you have different instances of the `Receive` service.   You can track instances using a ID field that generates a Guid for each instance.   I'm assuming `Receive` is a service and  `InstallServiceInfoReceived` is a standard event?  What's the scope?  Can you show the pertinent `Receive` code?

Comment: You are using async void for event listening. async void can cause unpredictable behavior such as you described. Use void and then call StateHasChanged on the component.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis I added the following code

Inside the ```if (contentType == "SVCMGMT/INSTALL/SVCINFO")```, it always came in, but sometimes ```OnServiceInfoReceived``` doesn't fire, and as a result it doesn't output to the page.

Comment: @MayurEkbote When I made that modification, I got the following exception.

System.InvalidOperationException: 'The current thread is not associated with the Dispatcher. Use InvokeAsync() to switch execution to the Dispatcher when triggering rendering or component state.'

Comment: @MayurEkbote Furthermore, when I debugged it, the ```OnServiceInfoReceived()``` itself wasn't called at all in the situation where it wasn't printed to the screen, so I don't think it was just a ```statehaschanged()``` issue.

Comment: What is the role being played by `receive.cs` and how is `ServiceInfoReceiveHandler.Receive()` invoked and from where?

Comment: @MisterMagoo ```receive.cs``` is responsible for receiving all the messages, and sending them to a handler determined by the contentType of the message received. Debugging with breakpoints, I can see that it works fine up to ```if (contentType == "SVCMGMT/INSTALL/SVCINFO")```. The problem is that ```InstallServiceInfoReceived?.Invoke(this, (contentType, serverName, message));``` is not executed, it just passes through and ```OnServiceInfoReceived()``` is not called. Why is invoke not executed?

Comment: Is your `Install` component a routed component occupying the whole "page" or is it placed on a page with other components where it could be re-rendered and possibly re-created?

Comment: @MisterMagoo Install.razor is the entire page responsible for the installation. It has an ```@page```.

Comment: OnServiceInfoReceived() won't be running on the UI thread, what do you do there?

Comment: @HH I do my work inside a function and then reflect the changes with ```await InvokeAsync(() => StateHasChanged()).ConfigureAwait(false);``` to reflect the change.

Comment: I would lose the ConfigureAwait, in case you _are_ running on the UI thread. That "sometimes it fails" does point to a threading issue.

Comment: @HH If I leave out ```ConfigureAwait``, I get the same problem. My problem is that ```InstallServiceInfoReceived``` has a null in it, so it never reaches ```OnServiceInfoReceived``` in the first place.

Comment: InstallServiceInfoReceived is an event and can never be `null`. How do you establish that OnServiceInfoReceived  is not called? Put a breakpoint in it.

Comment: @HH Yes, I noticed through the breakpoint that sometimes ```OnServiceInfoReceived``` is not called, so I checked to see why, and the value of ```InstallServiceInfoReceived``` in ```InstallServiceInfoReceived.Invoke()``` is null. (In a properly working situation, ```InstallServiceInfoReceived``` contains various values such as method, target, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you are dealing with a timing issue on component renders. There's nothing in the code you've shown to to make me believe otherwise.

Calling `StateHasChanged` doesn't render the component.  It queues the component's `RenderFragment` onto the Renderer's queue.  That queue only get's serviced [by the Renderer and the commponent rendered] when the Renderer get's thread time to run.

How are you establishing that it's only called sometimes?  By seeing or not seeing  UI updates or by logging?

To establish if that's the case add a `Console.Write` or `Debug.Writeline` inside the `if` and inside `OnServiceInfoReceived`.

You also need to apply the following pattern to your event handler.

```cs
private async void OnServiceInfoReceived(object sender, (string contentType, string serverName, string message) e)
{
   // do your async stuff 
   await this.InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
}
```

`ComponentBase` inherited components have a UI event handler that calls the event methods and calls `StateHasChanged` for you.   It doesn't handle event handlers,  So if you need the UI to update, you need to trigger a render manually by calling `StateHasChanged`. `ComponentBase` provides the InvokeAsync method to ensure the passed method is run by the dispatcher within the UI thread context.

Comment: I checked through the breakpoint and the problem is that it doesn't get to ```OnServiceInfoReceived()``` in the first place. I checked through debugging and it works fine up to ```if (contentType == "SVCMGMT/INSTALL/SVCINFO")```, but sometimes it just passes through without executing ```InstallServiceInfoReceived?.Invoke(this, (contentType, serverName, message))```;. It doesn't happen every time, but it happens sometimes. I'm not sure what the pattern is - it's not firing ```Invoke```, so of course ```OnServiceInfoReceived()``` isn't firing either. Why isn't Invoke firing?

Comment: You are sate to assume that if a handler is registered with a event it will get fired.  So if nothing is firing there's nothing registered . Add some debug code to print out who's registered on the event handler on each call.  Is `Install` a component within a page?  It it being destroyed and re-rendered?  Without a full view of the code it's hard to guide.

Comment: The event is not called if ```InstallServiceInfoReceived``` contains a ```null```, and in my tests, it happened after clicking the refresh button (f5).

```builder.Services.AddScoped<ServiceInfoReceiveHandler>();```

```@inject ServiceInfoReceiveHandler _serviceInfoReceiveHandler```

I'm registering and using the service as above, but could this be a problem?

Comment: Yes.  You're raising the event before you've registered the handler.  A timing issue.  Break points don't often help in isolating these issues because async tasks complete in the background.  You need to add `Debug.Writline` at various points to see what's happening in real time.  Where in `Receive` are you invoking the event?

Comment: Added ```message_broker.cs```. When a message comes through the message broker, it sends the message to the appropriate handler based on the content type. ```_handlers[contentType].Receive(ea);``` will cause ```receive()``` to be executed.  
Additionally, I found that registering the ```ServiceInfoReceiveHandler``` as ```addSingleton``` solved the problem, but I'm not sure if it's a good idea to do so. Can you advise me on this?

Comment: There's not enough information in your code to piece together how your services plug together or where the messages come from, so I can't comment on the singleton question.

Comment: Yes To explain my logic a bit more, I register an event in ```OnInitializedAsync``` of ```install.razor``` and send a status request message to the agent side. The agent side then sends a response message, which arrives at receive.cs via message_broker. After that, I raise the ```OnServiceInfoReceived``` event via ```InstallServiceInfoReceived?.Invoke(this, (contentType, serverName, message));```. This function puts the received value in a variable and reflects it on the screen via ```StateHasChanged``.

Comment: Each class is ```addscoped``` from ```program.cs``` and used via ```@inject``` on the razor page.(```_serviceInfoReceiveHandler```)

Comment: Questions: What's the scope of `MessageBroker`? Scoped? Who calls `ReceiveMessage`?  How do you send the status message request? Why do you call `ReceiveMessage();` in the `MessageBroker` constructor?

Comment: The ```MessageBroker``` is set to ```AddScoped```. The send action is performed the moment the ```install.razor`` page is loaded. On the agent side, which receives the message, we see that it is not missing anything and that it is receiving the request and passing the response.  The ```ReceiveMessage()``` merely calls the corresponding receive function based on the handler determined above, such as ```_handlers[contentType].Receive(ea);```.

Comment: Additionally, after pressing the refresh button (F5), the InstallServiceInfoReceived will always have a null value, which prevents the screen from updating. 
Even when I press f5, it does ```_serviceInfoReceiveHandler.InstallServiceInfoReceived += OnServiceInfoReceived;``` and then goes to meet ```.invoke```. I don't know why it keeps on being null even after meeting ```OnServiceInfoReceived```.